# Serverfault Tag Merge network/networking

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

I don't see logic behind a network and a networking tag, does anyone else?  Can they be merged into Networking if that is the case?

[`[network]`](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/network) (425)
[`[networking]`](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/networking) (1211)

Comment: Somewhat related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43828/su-retag-request-wireless-network-wireless-networking .  I thought quack brought up a good point, but he ended up making the change.

Comment: Please do another merge, and add a tag synonym for this: `[network]` is already back up to 59 questions.

Comment: @Jon Seigel:  This time I got to do it for myself :-)

Comment: Thanks... but... please add a synonym. Someone has *already* asked a new question with `[network]` on it.

Comment: @Jon Seigel: Ah did not know that feature had been added.  I created the requested synonym.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. FYI: when you add a synonym, currently all questions with the source tag aren't retagged automatically.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I think this probably will need to wait until [tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms) are available.  Until synonyms or a [blacklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list) is available people will continue to use the [network] tag.

Answer (score 4):

I did some research on that topic. I found no evidence that there were differences in usage of both terms. So I've gone ahead and merged the `[network]` tag into the (more often used) `[networking]` tag.